# AWS Cloudtrail - lookup-events for a specific trail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

How to lookup-events given a AWS CloudTrail name (/arn) ?

From AWS CloudTrail API documentation,I could not figure out if this feature is supported.
If there are multiple trials how does CloudTrail lookup-events work (or not)?

Comment: That's probably only AWS Console feature.